# Configure NetBeans IDE to use specific version of Java API

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using NetBeans 7.2.1.

My Java projects are compliant with Java 6, however it appears that NetBeans is using Java 7 as the compiler.

Java 7 modified some interfaces such as java.sql.Connection by adding more methods such as getNetworkTimeout().

This causes compile-time errors such as

```
error: MyConnection is not abstract and does not override abstract method getNetworkTimeout() in Connection
```

How can I configure NetBeans to use the Java 6 API?

- I have tried right-clicking project, Properties -> Sources -> Source/Binary Format: JDK 6.
- I have tried right-clicking project, Properties -> Build -> Compiling -> Additional Compiler Options: -source 1.6 -target 1.6

Neither of these solve my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add the Java 6 JDK to NetBeans: Tools -> Java Platforms
2. Use Java6 for your project: Project Properties -> Libraries -> Java Platform